# Postgres: clear entire database before re-creating / re-populating from bash script

Tags: database, backup, postgresql

I'm writing a shell script (will become a cronjob) that will:

1: dump my production database

2: import the dump into my development database

Between step 1 and 2, I need to clear the development database (drop all tables?). How is this best accomplished from a shell script? So far, it looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
time=`date '+%Y'-'%m'-'%d'`
# 1. export(dump) the current production database
pg_dump -U production_db_name > /backup/dir/backup-${time}.sql

# missing step: drop all tables from development database so it can be re-populated

# 2. load the backup into the development database
psql -U development_db_name < backup/dir/backup-${time}.sql
```

Comment: oneliner for people in a hurry: `dbname='db_name' && dropdb $dbname && createdb $dbname && psql -d $dbname -f dump.sql`

Comment: this oneliner requires you to have permissions to create/drop the database. the approach the author is trying doesn't require special privileges.

Answer (score 270, accepted):

I'd just drop the database and then re-create it. On a UNIX or Linux system, that should do it:

```
$ dropdb development_db_name
$ createdb development_db_name
```

That's how I do it, actually.

Comment: This is how I do it as well.  Then just restore into the newly created db.

Comment: yep. this is better because there may be objects that aren't part of the dump you are restoring. in this case they will definitely be killed.

Comment: Thanks, coming from a background with MySQL experience I keep forgetting about PostGres's command line tools.

Comment: one trick that saves me time is $ sudo -u postgres dropdb DATABASE_NAME

Comment: But... what about database permissions and ownership?

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini You could add a line to a script for postgres to change the database ownership to the specific user after the restore.  I run it manually when I import my production databases into development for testing, but I'm sure it could be scripted.

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini `createdb --owner=db_owner [--template=template0 --encoding=UTF8] db_name` i add the last two by default to all databases

Comment: It would be nicer if somebody could actually come up with a solution that doesn't require permissions to create or drop the database. if you're the database owner, you should be able to clear and fill as much as you want, as much as you keep the ownership of the name.

Comment: Does this automatically close all active connections? Because that's the issue I have when using DROP DATABASE within psql.

Comment: I got burned last year - when I transferred about eight databases (which were displaces on two servers) on one RDS postgres  instance - I didn't dropped the databases before restoring them...seven databases went fine..but the last one didn't restore correctly...I will never ever again restore a db without dropping it before..

Comment: I needed to do `sudo -u postgres dropdb database_name`

Comment: I want to keep the password

Comment: I did this and then `psql -d dbname -f latest-dbname.pgdump` on and it went fine. Permissions remained the same.

Answer (score 117):

If you don't actually need a backup of the database dumped onto disk in a plain-text .sql script file format, you could connect `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` directly together over a pipe.

To drop and recreate tables, you could use the `--clean` command-line option for `pg_dump` to emit SQL commands to clean (drop) database objects prior to (the commands for) creating them. (This will not drop the whole database, just each table/sequence/index/etc. before recreating them.)

The above two would look something like this:

```
pg_dump -U username --clean | pg_restore -U username
```

Comment: i like this solution, since i do want a backup copy, i'm now doing this:
pg_dump -Ft -U production_db_name > /backup/dir/backup-${time}.tar
pg_restore -U development_db_name -d development_db_name -O --clean /backup/dir/backup-${time}.tar
works like a charm, thanks for your help!

Comment: Beware: the --clean option only removes those relations found in the restore file. This means that if you add a table for testing, then want to remove it (to synchronise with the production DB for example), it will *not* be removed.

Comment: It's important to have in mind that pg_dump's *--clean* option only works with plain text backups. As the documentation clearly states here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pgdump.html, you need to use --clean on pg_restore for archived backups.

Comment: Is there any way to include cascade in "--clean" option. As it is this option looks useless. I'm getting 
"ERROR:  cannot drop schema public because other objects depend on it" like 100% of time using it.

Comment: The question asked about removing all tables. This only removes tables found in the database that pg_dump is dumping from.

Answer (score 31):

To dump:

```
pg_dump -Fc mydb > db.dump
```

To restore:

```
pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser -d my_db db/latest.dump
```

Answer (score 23):

If you want to clean your database named "example_db":

1) Login to another db(for example 'postgres'):

```
psql postgres
```

2) Remove your database:

```
DROP DATABASE example_db;
```

3) Recreate your database:

```
CREATE DATABASE example_db;
```

Answer (score 16):

## Clear database completely

Note: pg_dump & pg_restore don't fully clear the entire database.

```
DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA public;
```

If you are using PostgreSQL 9.3 or greater, you may also need to restore the default grants.

```
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO <your_db_username>;
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO public;
```

Answer (score 15):

Although the following line is taken from a windows batch script, the command should be quite similar:

```
psql -U username -h localhost -d postgres -c "DROP DATABASE \"$DATABASE\";"
```

This command is used to clear the whole database, by actually dropping it. The `$DATABASE` (in Windows should be `%DATABASE%`) in the command is a windows style environment variable that evaluates to the database name. You will need to substitute that by your `development_db_name`.

Comment: then why not use the already available `dropdb` and `createdb` commands? If you can run psql, you can run those as well.

Answer (score 14):

Note: my answer is about really deleting the tables and other database objects; for [deleting all data *in* the tables, i.e. truncating all tables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54832238/2171120), Endre Both has provided a similarily well-executed (direct execution) statement a month later.

For the cases where you can’t just `DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE;`, `DROP OWNED BY current_user;` or something, here’s a stand-alone SQL script I wrote, which is transaction-safe (i.e. you can put it between `BEGIN;` and either `ROLLBACK;` to just test it out or `COMMIT;` to actually do the deed) and cleans up “all” database objects… well, all those used in the database our application uses or I could sensibly add, which is:

- triggers on tables
- constraints on tables (FK, PK, `CHECK`, `UNIQUE`)
- indicēs
- `VIEW`s (normal or materialised)
- tables
- sequences
- routines (aggregate functions, functions, procedures)
- all nōn-default (i.e. not `public` or DB-internal) schemata “we” own: the script is useful when run as “not a database superuser”; a superuser can drop *all* schemata (the really important ones are still explicitly excluded, though)
- extensions (user-contributed but I normally deliberately leave them in)

Not dropped are (some deliberate; some only because I had no example in our DB):

- the `public` schema (e.g. for extension-provided stuff in them)
- collations and other locale stuff
- event triggers
- text search stuff, … (see [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalogs-overview.html) for other stuff I might have missed)
- roles or other security settings
- composite types
- toast tables
- FDW and foreign tables

This is **really** useful for the cases when the dump you want to restore is of a different database schema version (e.g. with Debian `dbconfig-common`, Flyway or Liquibase/DB-Manul) than the database you want to restore it into.

I’ve also got a version which deletes “everything except two tables and what belongs to them” (a sequence, tested manually, sorry, I know, boring) in case someone is interested; the diff is small. Contact me or [check this repo](https://evolvis.org/plugins/scmgit/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=useful-scripts/useful-scripts.git;a=tree;f=SQL;hb=HEAD) if interested.

### SQL

```
-- Copyright © 2019, 2020
--      mirabilos <t.glaser@tarent.de>
--
-- Provided that these terms and disclaimer and all copyright notices
-- are retained or reproduced in an accompanying document, permission
-- is granted to deal in this work without restriction, including un‐
-- limited rights to use, publicly perform, distribute, sell, modify,
-- merge, give away, or sublicence.
--
-- This work is provided “AS IS” and WITHOUT WARRANTY of any kind, to
-- the utmost extent permitted by applicable law, neither express nor
-- implied; without malicious intent or gross negligence. In no event
-- may a licensor, author or contributor be held liable for indirect,
-- direct, other damage, loss, or other issues arising in any way out
-- of dealing in the work, even if advised of the possibility of such
-- damage or existence of a defect, except proven that it results out
-- of said person’s immediate fault when using the work as intended.
-- -
-- Drop everything from the PostgreSQL database.

DO $$
DECLARE
        q TEXT;
        r RECORD;
BEGIN
        -- triggers
        FOR r IN (SELECT pns.nspname, pc.relname, pt.tgname
                FROM pg_catalog.pg_trigger pt, pg_catalog.pg_class pc, pg_catalog.pg_namespace pns
                WHERE pns.oid=pc.relnamespace AND pc.oid=pt.tgrelid
                    AND pns.nspname NOT IN ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog', 'pg_toast')
                    AND pt.tgisinternal=false
            ) LOOP
                EXECUTE format('DROP TRIGGER %I ON %I.%I;',
                    r.tgname, r.nspname, r.relname);
        END LOOP;
        -- constraints #1: foreign key
        FOR r IN (SELECT pns.nspname, pc.relname, pcon.conname
                FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint pcon, pg_catalog.pg_class pc, pg_catalog.pg_namespace pns
                WHERE pns.oid=pc.relnamespace AND pc.oid=pcon.conrelid
                    AND pns.nspname NOT IN ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog', 'pg_toast')
                    AND pcon.contype='f'
            ) LOOP
                EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE ONLY %I.%I DROP CONSTRAINT %I;',
                    r.nspname, r.relname, r.conname);
        END LOOP;
        -- constraints #2: the rest
        FOR r IN (SELECT pns.nspname, pc.relname, pcon.conname
                FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint pcon, pg_catalog.pg_class pc, pg_catalog.pg_namespace pns
                WHERE pns.oid=pc.relnamespace AND pc.oid=pcon.conrelid
                    AND pns.nspname NOT IN ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog', 'pg_toast')
                    AND pcon.contype<>'f'
            ) LOOP
                EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE ONLY %I.%I DROP CONSTRAINT %I;',
                    r.nspname, r.relname, r.conname);
        END LOOP;
        -- indicēs
        FOR r IN (SELECT pns.nspname, pc.relname
                FROM pg_catalog.pg_class pc, pg_catalog.pg_namespace pns
                WHERE pns.oid=pc.relnamespace
                    AND pns.nspname NOT IN ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog', 'pg_toast')
                    AND pc.relkind='i'
            ) LOOP
                EXECUTE format('DROP INDEX %I.%I;',
                    r.nspname, r.relname);
        END LOOP;
        -- normal and materialised views
        FOR r IN (SELECT pns.nspname, pc.relname
                FROM pg_catalog.pg_class pc, pg_catalog.pg_namespace pns
                WHERE pns.oid=pc.relnamespace
                    AND pns.nspname NOT IN ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog', 'pg_toast')
                    AND pc.relkind IN ('v', 'm')
            ) LOOP
                EXECUTE format('DROP VIEW %I.%I;',
                    r.nspname, r.relname);
        END LOOP;
        -- tables
        FOR r IN (SELECT pns.nspname, pc.relname
                FROM pg_catalog.pg_class pc, pg_catalog.pg_namespace pns
                WHERE pns.oid=pc.relnamespace
                    AND pns.nspname NOT IN ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog', 'pg_toast')
                    AND pc.relkind='r'
            ) LOOP
                EXECUTE format('DROP TABLE %I.%I;',
                    r.nspname, r.relname);
        END LOOP;
        -- sequences
        FOR r IN (SELECT pns.nspname, pc.relname
                FROM pg_catalog.pg_class pc, pg_catalog.pg_namespace pns
                WHERE pns.oid=pc.relnamespace
                    AND pns.nspname NOT IN ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog', 'pg_toast')
                    AND pc.relkind='S'
            ) LOOP
                EXECUTE format('DROP SEQUENCE %I.%I;',
                    r.nspname, r.relname);
        END LOOP;
        -- extensions (only if necessary; keep them normally)
        FOR r IN (SELECT pns.nspname, pe.extname
                FROM pg_catalog.pg_extension pe, pg_catalog.pg_namespace pns
                WHERE pns.oid=pe.extnamespace
                    AND pns.nspname NOT IN ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog', 'pg_toast')
            ) LOOP
                EXECUTE format('DROP EXTENSION %I;', r.extname);
        END LOOP;
        -- aggregate functions first (because they depend on other functions)
        FOR r IN (SELECT pns.nspname, pp.proname, pp.oid
                FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc pp, pg_catalog.pg_namespace pns, pg_catalog.pg_aggregate pagg
                WHERE pns.oid=pp.pronamespace
                    AND pns.nspname NOT IN ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog', 'pg_toast')
                    AND pagg.aggfnoid=pp.oid
            ) LOOP
                EXECUTE format('DROP AGGREGATE %I.%I(%s);',
                    r.nspname, r.proname,
                    pg_get_function_identity_arguments(r.oid));
        END LOOP;
        -- routines (functions, aggregate functions, procedures, window functions)
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute
                WHERE attrelid='pg_catalog.pg_proc'::regclass
                    AND attname='prokind' -- PostgreSQL 11+
            ) THEN
                q := 'CASE pp.prokind
                        WHEN ''p'' THEN ''PROCEDURE''
                        WHEN ''a'' THEN ''AGGREGATE''
                        ELSE ''FUNCTION''
                    END';
        ELSIF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute
                WHERE attrelid='pg_catalog.pg_proc'::regclass
                    AND attname='proisagg' -- PostgreSQL ≤10
            ) THEN
                q := 'CASE pp.proisagg
                        WHEN true THEN ''AGGREGATE''
                        ELSE ''FUNCTION''
                    END';
        ELSE
                q := '''FUNCTION''';
        END IF;
        FOR r IN EXECUTE 'SELECT pns.nspname, pp.proname, pp.oid, ' || q || ' AS pt
                FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc pp, pg_catalog.pg_namespace pns
                WHERE pns.oid=pp.pronamespace
                    AND pns.nspname NOT IN (''information_schema'', ''pg_catalog'', ''pg_toast'')
            ' LOOP
                EXECUTE format('DROP %s %I.%I(%s);', r.pt,
                    r.nspname, r.proname,
                    pg_get_function_identity_arguments(r.oid));
        END LOOP;
        -- nōn-default schemata we own; assume to be run by a not-superuser
        FOR r IN (SELECT pns.nspname
                FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace pns, pg_catalog.pg_roles pr
                WHERE pr.oid=pns.nspowner
                    AND pns.nspname NOT IN ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog', 'pg_toast', 'public')
                    AND pr.rolname=current_user
            ) LOOP
                EXECUTE format('DROP SCHEMA %I;', r.nspname);
        END LOOP;
        -- voilà
        RAISE NOTICE 'Database cleared!';
END; $$;
```

Tested, except later additions (`extensions` contributed by [Clément Prévost](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/65636)), on PostgreSQL 9.6 (`jessie-backports`). Aggregate removal tested on 9.6 and 12.2, procedure removal tested on 12.2 as well. Bugfixes and further improvements welcome!

Answer (score 10):

I've used:

```
pg_restore -c -d database_name filename.dump
```