# How do you wipe a Postgresql database?

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm sending queries through Django on a PaaS service, and I think I can't access any command line utilities. I would have just dropped the entire database and recreated it, but I don't have permissions for that.

I'm looking for a simple command that would return the database to a completely virgin state.

Comment: see also: [Drop all tables in postgresql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327312/drop-all-tables-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you could cascade drop the schema and then drop the db:

```
drop schema myschema CASCADE;
drop database mydb;
```

if you do not have the rights to do so, you will have to drop table by table.

EDIT: If you can only drop tables, this will give you the SQL statements to run:

```
select 'drop table '||schemaname||'.'||tablename||' CASCADE;' 
from pg_tables where schemaname = 'myschema' order by schemaname, tablename;
```