# escaping quotes in psql command for fabric script

Tags: python, bash, shell, fabric, psql

building on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327312/drop-all-tables-in-postgresql), I'm trying to delete all tables in my postgresql database with a fabric command. The bash command I'm trying to run is

```
#!/bin/bash
TABLES=`psql $PGDB -t --command "SELECT string_agg(table_name, ',') FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='public'"`

echo Dropping tables:${TABLES}
psql $PGDB --command "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ${TABLES} CASCADE"
```

which inside my fab script becomes:

```
def delete_tables():
    the_command = "SELECT string_agg(table_name, ',') FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='public'"
    run("TABLES=`psql -U db_user -d db_name $PGDB -t --command %s`" % the_command)
```

but the error is, `Peer authentication failed for user "string_agg"`. Which seems to indicate the command is not considered as a command between " ", but a long single string ...

I've tried converting:
`'`  into  `'\''`
but no luck.  Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `pipes.quote()` to quote something that goes to the shell.

```
import pipes
def delete_tables():
    the_command = "SELECT string_agg(table_name, ',') FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='public'"
    run("TABLES=`psql -U db_user -d db_name $PGDB -t --command %s`" % pipes.quote(the_command))
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know pipes.quote()

Answer (score 4):

Don't shell out for this kind of task. Use [`psycopg`](http://initd.org/psycopg/) instead:

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(database='db_name', user='db_user')
cur  = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT string_agg(table_name, ',') FROM ...;")
for record in cur:
    print record
```

Comment: +1 `psql` is primarily for interactive exploration of a database, not an API for use within other programs.

Comment: Thank you for adding that perspective. This seems more elegant and appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

This should work without the need for any other imports:

```
def delete_tables():
run('''psql -U db_user -d db_name $PGDB -t -c "SELECT string_agg(table_name, ',') FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='public';"''')
```