# How to "reset" postgresql database?

Tags: django, postgresql

I am trying to move my django project into a production environment and in doing so I switched from using sqlite to postgres.  In my development environment, whenever I made changes to my models or anything that would significantly change how the database was setup, I would literally just drag my sqlite file to the trash and just run syncdb to create a new empty one (probably bad practice).  Now that I am using postgres, I am wanting to do the same thing without actually deleting the database.  Basically I was wondering if there was a way to completely empty it or clear it out and then just run syncdb and start over?

I also welcome any alternative suggestions that might lead me down the right path, I'm very new to this.

Comment: Read the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21247009/548165

Answer (score 8):

You can use [flush](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#flush). Just run this command:

```
python manage.py flush
```

Comment: So I could make changes to my existing models and add new ones, and then just use the flush command and syncdb?

Comment: what is "initial data"

Comment: U won't need to use syncdb while using flush. Flush clears out the data from db but not the structure

Comment: the link is broken

Comment: Yes, it should work on every table regardless of any databases.

Answer (score 5):

First if you have [initial data in your database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/initial-data/) you can use [dumbpdata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-dumpdata) command:

```
python manage.py dumpdata > initial_data.json
```

For specific app run:

```
python manage.py dumpdata <app_name> > initial_data.json
```

Second run the [flush](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#flush) command to clean your database:

```
python manage.py flush
```

Third and last, run [loaddata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-loaddata) command to load the initial data into your database and create superuser by running [createsuperuser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#createsuperuser) command

```
python manage.py loaddata initial_data.json
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Comment: What is the 'initial data' ?  I am trying to remove ALL of the data, not specific app data.

Answer (score 0):

In case flush does not work, you can drop the whole database.

Go to windows command line.
If server is 'postgres' and db name is 'mydb', run:

1. `C:\> psql -U postgres`
2. You will see a postgres-# prompt. Next is to close connections running the following:

   SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname='mydb';
   SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE datname = 'mydb';
3. Drop database once for all: `DROP DATABASE mydb;`