# How do I remove all tables and not the schema in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a schema assigned to my user (jason).  I can't remove the schema as I don't have permissions to do so.
Is there a nice way to remove each tables, data, everything in a schema and make it as if I had a freshly created schema.
Basically the same effect as:

```
drop schema jason cascade;
create schema jason;
```

But without the actually dropping the schema.

Comment: I guess the best way would be to generate the list of DROP TABLE statements from the infomration_schema.tables and then run all them at once.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The accepted answer is great, but you can do this in just one step taking advantage from anonymous blocks (PosgreSQL 9.0+):

```
DO $$
DECLARE 
    r record;
BEGIN
    FOR r IN SELECT quote_ident(tablename) AS tablename, quote_ident(schemaname) AS schemaname FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname = 'public'
    LOOP
        RAISE INFO 'Dropping table %.%', r.schemaname, r.tablename;
        EXECUTE format('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %I.%I CASCADE', r.schemaname, r.tablename);
    END LOOP;
END$$;
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this from psql:

```
-- Turn off headers:
\t
-- Use SQL to build SQL:
select 'drop table if exists "' || tablename || '" cascade;' 
  from pg_tables
 where schemaname = 'jason'; 
-- If the output looks good, write it to a file and run it:
\g out.tmp
\i out.tmp
```

from [stackoverflow.com/questions/3327312/drop-all-tables-in-postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327312/drop-all-tables-in-postgresql)

Comment: I would also like to comment that this only creates the set of commands that you need to run after this to make delete the table.

Comment: Yes and NO, yes create the command set and run they.

Comment: Alternative: use \gexec instead of \g & \i