# How I do destroy all tables for schema in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have some tables in schema public's;

I want destroy all tables at schema. Like DROP TABLE public.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drop all tables in postgresql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327312/drop-all-tables-in-postgresql)

Comment: I didn't have authority for public schema

Comment: If you have found a solution for your own question, you should write an answer to yourself.

Comment: `drop owned by your_user_name`. Or  `drop schema public cascade; create schema public` if there are tables owned by different users.

Answer (score 3):

I usually do it like this (I've commented execution of the query, it will only be printed):

```
do $$
declare
    rec record;
    query text;
begin
    for rec in select * from pg_tables where schemaname = 'public'
    loop
        query = format('drop table %s.%s', rec.schemaname, rec.tablename);
        raise notice '%', query;
        --execute query;
    end loop;
end
$$ language plpgsql;
```

I use cool [DO](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html) thing when I just want to execute some code but don't want to create a stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks! this my wanna answer.

Comment: You're welcome! If this really works for you then you should mark this answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

If all of the tables are in the same schema (public):

DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE;

CREATE SCHEMA public;