# Running queries without having to manually delete created tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, create-table

New to SQL, using PostgreSQL.

I'm trying a few beginner problems, but I have a problem.
To make sure I don't run into any unknown errors while testing things, I'm writing the queries in steps i.e

```
CREATE TABLE x(...);

...

run query..

CREATE TABLE x(...);

CREATE TABLE y(...);

run query
```

--- and so on.

Problem is, after I created a table, I have to delete it if I want to try and run the query again, otherwise I get the

> 'ERROR: relation "x" already exists.'

Seems like a trivial problem, but after looking around in stackoverflow, google, postgre's website, I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can either drop the table if it exists, or create the table if it doesn't exist, depending on your needs.

`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tableName ...`

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableName ...`

Check out the documenation for [creating a table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtable.html) or [dropping a table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-droptable.html).

Comment: but let's say I changed something in one of the tables, will it still delete it? or will it read it as a 'new' table?

Comment: @Immanuel If you drop the table, it will delete everything. But if you create a new table that already exists, it will just append rows to the table, leaving all existing data in place.

Comment: so I would have to use the 'IF NOT EXISTS' for each table I create correct? is there anything 'all inclusive'?

Comment: You can also [drop all the tables at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327312/drop-all-tables-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use temporary tables -- unless you have specific performance (or other) reasons for doing so.

Instead use common table expressions (CTEs):

```
with x as (
      <code here>
     ),
     y as (
      <code here>
     ),
     . . .
select . . .
```

CTEs are part of the query, so they do not persist between query runs.  Voila!  No problem with naming or temporary tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you're really just practicing and the data isn't important you can use `TEMPORARY` tables. Then a simple disconnect and reconnect throws them away and gives you a clean slate.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE x(...);
```

Or you can even use transaction-scoped temp tables, which are dropped on commit or rollback:

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE x(...) ON COMMIT DROP;

INSERT ...

COMMIT;
```

Or, of course, you can just do your iterative development in a transaction that you `ROLLBACK` at the end.

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TABLE x(...);

INSERT ...

ROLLBACK;
```

Comment: I get a different 'ERROR:  constraints on permanent tables may reference only permanent tables'

Comment: @Immanuel You'd have to use all temp, or all permanent, tables in your tests. You can't have a foreign key constraint from a permanent table to a temp one or vice versa.