# Executing a script generated by an SQL Query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm fairly new to Postgres, and I'm wondering if there is a way to run strings as queries (not in PL/pgSQL, I get that that's not something you can do in the psql prompt). Specifically, in questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3327326/), you generate a batch script using a query, like this:

```
select 'drop table if exists "' || tablename || '" cascade;' from pg_tables;
```

But how do you run it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not using plpgsql? You can do it using [anonymous blocks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html):

```
DO $$
DECLARE 
    r record;
BEGIN
    FOR r IN SELECT schemaname, tablename FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname = 'my_schema'
    LOOP
        RAISE INFO 'Dropping table: %.%', r.schemaname, r.tablename;
        EXECUTE format('DROP TABLE %I.%I', r.schemaname, r.tablename);
    END LOOP;
END$$;
```

And yes, it works on psql.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that. I just didn't know you can embed plpgsql in psql like that :)

Comment: Glad to help you @NiayeshIsky