# Drop all tables in a Redshift schema - without dropping permissions

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I would be interested to drop all tables in a Redshift schema. Even though this solution works

```
DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA public;
```

is **NOT** good for me since that it drops SCHEMA permissions as well.

A solution like

```
DO $$ DECLARE
r RECORD;
BEGIN
    -- if the schema you operate on is not "current", you will want to
    -- replace current_schema() in query with 'schematodeletetablesfrom'
    -- *and* update the generate 'DROP...' accordingly.
    FOR r IN (SELECT tablename FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname = current_schema()) LOOP
        EXECUTE 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ' || quote_ident(r.tablename) || ' CASCADE';
    END LOOP;
END $$;
```

as reported in this thread [How can I drop all the tables in a PostgreSQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327312/how-can-i-drop-all-the-tables-in-a-postgresql-database)
would be ideal. Unfortunately it doesn't work on Redshift (apparently there is no support for `for loops`).

Is there any other solution to achieve it?

Comment: Write the loop in python or some other scripting language, external to your cluster?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Run this SQL and copy+paste the result on your SQL client.
If you want to do it programmatically you need to built little bit code around it.

```
SELECT 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ' || tablename || ' CASCADE;' 
FROM pg_tables 
WHERE schemaname = '<your_schema>'
```

Comment: would you please format correctly the SQL query to improve readability of your answer?

Answer (score 2):

I solved it through a procedure that deletes all records. Using this technique to truncate fails but deleting it works fine for my intents and purposes.

```
create or replace  procedure sp_truncate_dwh() as $$

DECLARE 
    tables RECORD;

BEGIN

FOR tables in   SELECT tablename 
                FROM pg_tables 
                WHERE  schemaname = 'dwh'  
                order by tablename
        LOOP
        EXECUTE 'delete from dwh.' || quote_ident(tables.tablename) ;
        END LOOP;
RETURN;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

--call sp_truncate_dwh()
```

Comment: Procedures in Redshift have been available only since 17 May 2019
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/05/amazon-redshift-now-supports-stored-procedures/
So this could be an interesting solution by using procedures, I'll give it a try

Answer (score 1):

Using Python and [pyscopg2](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/) locally on my PC I came up with this script to delete all tables in `schema`:

```
import psycopg2


schema = "schema_to_be_deleted"
try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='{}' port='{}' host='{}' user='{}' password='{}'".format("DB_NAME", "DB_PORT", "DB_HOST", "DB_USER", "DB_PWD"))
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute("SELECT tablename FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname = '%s'" % schema)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        cursor.execute("DROP TABLE {}.{}".format(schema, row[0]))

    cursor.close()
    conn.commit()

except psycopg2.DatabaseError as error:
    logger.error(error)
finally:
    if conn is not None:
        conn.close()
```

Replace correctly values for `DB_NAME`, `DB_PORT`, `DB_HOST`, `DB_USER` and `DB_PWD` to connect to the Redshift DB

Comment: How do you import the library?

Comment: if you're referring to `psycopg2` I think an easy `pip install psycopg2` should do the job if you use pip as a packet manager https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/

Comment: Shouldn't that library be imported in AWS? To be used in AWS?

Comment: @Henrov I executed this Python script into my local PC as a client and connected to Redshift cluster through credentials, just like any other DBMS

Answer (score 1):

In addition to demircioglu's answer, I had to add Commit after every drop statement to drop all tables in my schema. `SELECT 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ' || tablename || ' CASCADE; COMMIT;' FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname = '<your_schema>'`
P.S.: I do not have required reputation to add this note as a comment and had to add as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following recipe differs from other answers in the regard that it generates one SQL statement for all tables we're going to delete.

```sql
SELECT
    'DROP TABLE ' ||
    LISTAGG("table", ', ') ||
    ';'
FROM
    svv_table_info
WHERE
    "table" LIKE 'staging_%';
```

Example result:

```sql
DROP TABLE staging_077815128468462e9de8ca6fec22f284, staging_abc, staging_123;
```

As in other answers, you will need to copy the generated SQL and execute it separately.

### References

- [||](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_concat_op.html) operator concatenates strings
- [LISTAGG](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LISTAGG.html) function concatenates every table name into a string with a separator
- The table `svv_table_info` is used because `LISTAGG` doesn't want to work with `pg_tables` for me. Complaint:

> One or more of the used functions must be applied on at least one user created tables. Examples of user table only functions are LISTAGG, MEDIAN, PERCENTILE_CONT, etc

**UPD.** I just now noticed that [SVV_TABLE_INFO](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SVV_TABLE_INFO.html) page says:

> The `SVV_TABLE_INFO` view doesn't return any information for empty tables.

...which means empty tables will not be in the list returned by this query. I usually delete transient tables to save disk space, so this does not bother me much; but in general this factor should be considered.