# How to delete every table in a specific schema in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-schema, drop-table

How do I delete all the tables I have in a specific schema? Only the tables in the schema should be deleted. 
I already have all the table names that I fetched with the code below, but how do delete all those tables?

The following is some psycopg2 code, and below that is the SQL generated

```
writeCon.execute("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='mySchema'")
```

`SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='mySchema'`

Comment: here's a link to a question that might have the answers you need:[How can I drop all the tables in a PostgreSQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327312/how-can-i-drop-all-the-tables-in-a-postgresql-database)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use an [`anonymous code block`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) for that.

**WARNING**:  This code is playing with `DROP TABLE` statements, and they are really mean if you make a mistake ;) The `CASCADE` option drops all depending objects as well. Use it with care!

```
DO $$
DECLARE
  row record;
BEGIN
    FOR row IN SELECT * FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname = 'mySchema' 
    LOOP
      EXECUTE 'DROP TABLE mySchema.' || quote_ident(row.tablename) || ' CASCADE';
    END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

In case you want to drop everything in your schema, including wrappers, sequences, etc., consider dropping the schema itself and creating it again:

```
DROP SCHEMA mySchema CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA mySchema;
```

Comment: I am sure how to call such statements with psycopg2, unfortunately.

Comment: what happens if you pass this code inside the `writeCon.execute()` function?e.g. `writeCon.execute("DO $$
DECLARE
  row record;
BEGIN
    FOR row IN SELECT * FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname = 'mySchema' 
    LOOP
      EXECUTE 'DROP TABLE mySchema.' || quote_ident(row.tablename);            
    END LOOP;
END;
$$;")`

Comment: it says that I need to add a Cascade because there are some dependencies. Where do I add that?

Comment: @GoldenRetriever try adding a `CASCADE` to the drop table statement: `DROP TABLE mySchema.' || quote_ident(row.tablename) CASCADE;`

Comment: Error:

psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "CASCADE"
LINE 3: 'mySchema.' || quote_ident(row.tablename) CASCADE; E...

Comment: something like this: `writeCon.execute("DO $$
DECLARE
  row record;
BEGIN
    FOR row IN SELECT * FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname = 'mySchema' 
    LOOP
      EXECUTE 'DROP TABLE mySchema.' || quote_ident(row.tablename) || ' CASCADE';
    END LOOP;
END;
$$;")`

Comment: It works. Thanks :) What is this syntax ? I am new to SQL but have never seen this kind of syntax.

Answer (score 4):

For a single-line command, you can use `psql` and its `\gexec` functionality:

```sql
SELECT format('DROP TABLE %I.%I', table_schema, table_name)
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema= 'mySchema';\gexec
```

That will run the query and execute each result string as SQL command.

Comment: What is \gexec ?

Comment: @GoldenRetriever see the [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html)

Comment: Invalid command \gexec. Try \? for help.

Comment: @RaulChiarella it seems you have added an extra `.` after the command.

Comment: No dot. Just copied pasted exactly as it is, it is postgres that adds the dot.