# Loop in INSERT contition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new in sql and it is not clear form me how I can do next:
I have code:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (val1, val2)
   SELECT table2.val1, table2.val2
FROM table2
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT count FROM table_log 
   WHERE event_id = table2.id)
   AND table2.type = 'user' -- AND table2.type = 'admin'
   AND table2.size1 > 4 -- AND table2.size2 > 2 (if user admin)
```

I need change this query to run also condition `AND table2.type = 'admin'`, which means `table2.val1, table2.val1` will be different, also condition `AND table2.size1 > 4` should be changes to `AND table2.size2 > 2`

Of course I can run this query 2 times with different value, but maybe it is possible to do in one query

Comment: have you checked `anonymous code blocks`? e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59720796/2275388

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: are you looking something other than "AND ((table2.type = 'user' AND table2.size1 > 4) OR (table2.type = 'admin' AND table2.size2 > 2)) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply modify the `WHERE` clause to achieve this in one pass:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (val1, val2)
   SELECT table2.val1, table2.val2
FROM table2
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT count FROM table_log 
   WHERE event_id = table2.id)
     AND (   (table2.type = 'user' AND table2.size1 > 4)
          OR (table2.type = 'admin' AND table2.size2 > 2)
         )
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it may not really good way, but you can run these two queries at the same time with `common table expressions (cte)`

```
WITH cte AS (
 INSERT INTO table1 (val1, val2)
   SELECT table2.val1, table2.val2
 FROM table2
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT count FROM table_log 
   WHERE event_id = table2.id)
   AND table2.type = 'user' -- AND table2.type = 'admin'
   AND table2.size1 > 4
) INSERT INTO table1 (val1, val2)
   SELECT table2.val1, table2.val2
FROM table2
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT count FROM table_log 
   WHERE event_id = table2.id)
   AND table2.type = 'admin'
   AND table2.size1 > 2
```