# Select drop table if exists from PSQL truncation trick is not working

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgres server with 2 databases on it, `db1` and `db2`. The second one, `db2` has lots of tables in it.

I want to keep both of these databases, but would like to "truncate" (delete all tables from) `db2`. My best attempt thus far is:

```
db2=# \c db1
You are now connected to database "db1" as user "postgres".
db1=# SELECT 'drop table if exists "' || tablename || '" cascade;' as pg_drop FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname='db2';

postgres=# \c db2
You are now connected to database "db2" as user "postgres".
db2=# \dt
 public | agent_machines                | table | muyapp_admin
 public | agent_message_queue           | table | muyapp_admin
 public | agent_pools                   | table | muyapp_admin
 public | alerts                        | table | muyapp_admin
 ...
```

And clearly, its not working, since there are still tables in `db2` after I do the `SELECT`.

**Can anyone spot where I'm going awry?**

Comment: First: you are running a `SELECT` statement - that will never drop anything. And a schema is something different than a databases. If your database  `db1` does not contain a **schema** named `db2` then obviously the select doesn't return anything. And even if your query returned something **and** you used `\gexec` after the SELECT statement to run those statements that would have dropped (not "deleted") all tables in `db1` as you connect to that database. The tables in the other database are completely unaffected. I think you are confusing schema with database.

Comment: OK so what exact command(s) do I need to run so that, afterwards, `db2` still exists, but is completely empty?

Comment: Well, your SELECT is OK, but it needs to be run in `db2` not `db1` and you apparently want to get rid of the restriction on the schema. Once your SELECT returns the correct list of statements, you can use `\gexec` to execute that. But it all needs to be done while connected to `db2` as you want to drop the tables _there_.

Comment: OK Thanks, but just to be clear, I could care less about the schema. I'm only going based on examples I've patched together from examples on the internet. All I care about is that `db2` is empty, but that all the users that have `GRANTs` to use the `db2` database remain in place. If ignorance is bliss, I could care less about any schema (if that helps you clue me in any better!).

Comment: so you'd need to connect to `db2`, then run your `SELECT` statement, then copy the sql commands it returns and paste them into the terminal. I assume you're trying to follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327312/how-can-i-drop-all-the-tables-in-a-postgresql-database?rq=1

Comment: OK so the only problem there is, look at the `SELECT` statement I have above. As soon as I enter it, I get a blank space (empty line) directly beneath it. So there's no actual SQL commands being returned there. Or are you saying that if I was connected to `db2`, there would be?

Comment: Obviously you have no tables in the `db2` **schema** - if you don't care about the schema, then remove the WHERE clause from your SELECT statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to drop tables in the database `db2` then you need to connect to **that** database. If you want to drop the tables regardless of the schema they are stored in, remove the `WHERE` clause that limits the list of tables to that specific schema (do you really have a *schema* named `db2` in a database named `db2` as well?)

You also need to include the schema name in the `drop` statement. Typically dynamic SQL is best generated using the `format()` function:

```
postgres=# \c db2
You are now connected to database "db2" as user "postgres".
postgres=# SELECT format('drop table %I.%I cascade;', schemaname, tablename)
FROM pg_tables 
WHERE schemaname not in ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema');
```

If you are satisfied with the result of that query, then end the statement with `\gexec` instead of the `;` which will make `psql` run the result of that query as a script - which will run each DROP statement.